# Why don't the Mr Meeseeks just kill themselves?

Tags: rick-and-morty

In the *Rick and Morty* episode "Meeseeks and Destroy", Rick gives the family a Meeseeks box to help them out. This box creates a being called Mr Meeseeks, whose only goal is to fulfill any request made of it before dying.

Jerry's request is to take 2 strokes off his golf game, which proves difficult for Mr Meeseeks and results in his intial Mr Meeseeks requesting help from an additional Mr Meeseeks. When that fails, the additional Mr Meeseeks also calls for help from a third Mr Meeseeks, the cycle continuing until there are dozens, if not more, Mr Meeseeks.

One of the Mr Meeseeks says that Mr Meeseeks' aren't meant to live as long as they are now, and that things are getting weird.

> Out of desperation, the end up attempting to kill Jerry, thereby taking all the strokes off his game and fulfilling their request. Jerry has to prove his golf skills under pressure in order to survive.

But why do the Mr Meeseeks not simply kill themselves, if death is their end goal anyway?

Comment: because if they killed themselves, they would have failed to fulfill Jerry's request before dying...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

During the episode, one of the Meeseeks (Mr Meeseeks, if I remember correctly) says "None of us can die until our job is done!" which either means that they have an aversion to dying before completing their tasks or-- more likely, given that it's *this* show-- the Meeseeks are actually *incapable* of dying until their tasks are complete.

Quote starts at 1:37 of this clip:

Comment: +1 I agree that this is the implication, especially since some of the Meeseeks are torn to shreds in the resulting tumble and still don't die.

Comment: Video is unavailable.

Answer (score 7):

Although from what I can remember this is not explicitly explained in the actual episode, it seemed to me at the time that Mr. Meseeks must have had some sort of natural aversion to suicide or, more likely, was somehow structurally limited in his ability to carry out such a task. Based on the fact that he is a supernatural creature summoned from a small object, has a pale blue color, and exists only to fulfill the desires of his summoner, I took Mr. Meseeks to be a perverted riff on the classic genie in the lamp formula - specifically as it was depicted in the Disney film Aladdin. If you look at the character this way it becomes fairly natural to assume that, just like the genie of the lamp was unable to use his magic to set himself free unilaterally, so Mr. Meseeks lacks the power to set himself free (in this case by killing himself before his task is complete). Things have to be this way, otherwise every genie would simply set themselves free as their first action, and every Mr. Meseeks would simply kill himself as soon as he is generated, thus defeating the point of both characters.